# Python 3 - tkinter , ignore socket.herror and continue

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, networking, tkinter

I try to resolve hosts using socket module via GUI I made using Tkinter
here is part of the code , the main issue is the error I receive while resolving routers name

```
for line in p.stdout:
            fiw = open("1.txt", '+a')
            line = str(line)
            if "Received = 1" in line:
                hostad = socket.gethostbyaddr(ip3 +str(i))
                if hostad:
                    try:
                        print(hostad)
                    except socket.herror:
                        print(hostad)
                fiw.write("Received reply from " + ip3 +str(i)+"\n")
                print("Received reply from " + ip3 +str(i)+"\n")
                print(socket.gethostbyaddr(ip3 +str(i)))
```

the error :

```
socket.herror: [Errno 11004] host not found
```

script won't run further i used `print` here just for example also i tried `pass`
tried

```
except socket.herror as err:
              print(err)
              pass
```

also tried just using `pass` in this method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have try ... except around the wrong thing,
instead of

```
hostad = socket.gethostbyaddr(ip3 +str(i))
if hostad:
    try:
        print(hostad)
    except socket.herror:
        print(hostad)
```

it should be like

```
try:
    hostad = socket.gethostbyaddr(ip3 +str(i))
    print(hostad)
except socket.herror:
    pass # code to execute in case of error
```

The error message itself refers to "Reverse DNS Lookup Failure"
as explained in [Python Sockets: gethostbyaddr : Reverse DNS Lookup Failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19169412/python-sockets-gethostbyaddr-reverse-dns-lookup-failure)

If the hostname formed in line

```
hostad = socket.gethostbyaddr(ip3 +str(i))
```

does not have a reverse DNS record, the exception is thrown.

Comment: Do you know other solution to get device version / name , like nmap does?

Answer (score -2):

i think that you should take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994334/make-python-code-continue-after-exception)

an exception is like a break point, it breaks your for loop..

try it like this :

```
for line in p.stdout:
   try:
        fiw = open("1.txt", '+a')
        line = str(line)
        if "Received = 1" in line:
            hostad = socket.gethostbyaddr(ip3 +str(i))
            if hostad:
                try:
                    print(hostad)
                except socket.herror:
                    print(hostad)
            fiw.write("Received reply from " + ip3 +str(i)+"\n")
            print("Received reply from " + ip3 +str(i)+"\n")
            print(socket.gethostbyaddr(ip3 +str(i)))
   except:
            pass
```

Comment: The `inner try ... except` is quite pointless, `print` never throws `socket.herror`. The outer `try ... except` catches every exception which is usually bad practise.