# Python lookup computer name on a domain by its IP address

Tags: python

I`m trying to get the name of a server in our lab domain.
When trying to execute the below - it says socket.herror: [Errno 11004] host not found :

`socket.gethostbyaddr("10.101.31.211")`

Any ideas?

Comment: is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19169412/python-sockets-gethostbyaddr-reverse-dns-lookup-failure) helps?

Comment: or this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832264/difficulty-using-pythons-socket-gethostbyaddr

Comment: Nope....still the same...I am lost...maybe it is not doable? to get the remote server name? i mean how hard is it?

Comment: If there is no problem, would it be possible that this is a valid IP address with no hostname, in which it would obviously have a socket.herror. Did you check that?